# How to increase the performance of table having 50 millions records and growing

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

We have two tables, table A and table B (contains 50 million records). In table A, we stored a unique value of merchant. From that, we fetched records from table B. How to increase the performance of query and what are the ways to increase performance for it?

Note: The table structure for both tables is simple.
Table A - storage engine (MyISAM)
TABLE B - storage engine (MyISAM)
In table A we have one primary key corresponding to table B's many records.
Queries Used:
**Query 1:**

```
records = "select field1, field2...  from table A where merchant_id = ''   
and field_date between '23-06-2012' and '23-06-2015' order by field 1";
```

**Query 2: execute in loop**

```
  foreach (records as records) {
      "select field_b1, field_b2, .. from table B where field_b1 =    
'records['field1']'"
   }
```

Comment: where is your query and what is table structure.

Comment: Purchase faster server (an SSD instead of mechanical drive), give it a lot of RAM, configure MySQL to utilize such hardware. Anything else?

Comment: You're not giving us a lot to work with.

Comment: A `show create table tblnm` output for both tables wouldn't break anyones heart here. Hand-typed gibberish doesn't count or help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done it, add indexes on `table_a.merchant_id` and `table_a.field_date`.
Also add indexes on `table_2.field_b1`.

In addition, you could try to make the main `select` on `table_b`, `join` it with the records from `table_a`. Something like:

```
select 
B.field_b1, B.field_b2 
from table_b AS B 
LEFT JOIN table_a AS A on B.field_b1 = A.field_1
WHERE A.merchant_id = '' AND A.field_date between '23-06-2012' and '23-06-2015' 
order by field 1;
```

This way you have only one query for all your records instead of 1 main query + who knows how many additional queries for each record found in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the logic to be a single query.  And, use ISO-standard date formats:

```
select a.field1, a.field2... , b.field1, b.field2, . . 
from a left join
     b
     on a.field1 = b.field1
where a.merchant_id = '' and
      a.field_date between '2012-06-23' and '2015-06-23'
order by a.field1;
```

For this query, you want indexes on:  `a(merchant_id, field_date, field1)` and `b(field1)`.

Note:  if you are only looking for one date, don't use `between`.  Just use `=`:

```
select a.field1, a.field2... , b.field1, b.field2, . . 
from a left join
     b
     on a.field1 = b.field1
where a.merchant_id = '' and
      a.field_date = '2012-06-23'
order by a.field1;
```

The query should run faster.